# MapBox get visibleCoordinateBounds in a CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I'm working on an iOS app with a *MapBox* map.

I'm displaying *MGLAnnotations* but I only want to create the annotations that can be seen on the screen at a current moment.

Problem is : I have a *UIView* on the bottom of my screen so the bounds I get with *mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds* function is not really accurate because I can't see the bottom of my map.

I can't just resize my map because the bottom view I talked about doesn't cover the entire map, we still see parts of the map behind the bottom view.

So my question is, how can I get the *visibleCoordinateBounds* for a *CGRect* over my *MapView* ?

My current solution works only for the entire map view bounds and not the bounds of the *CGRect* area I want to display the annotations :

```
if ((mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw).latitude...(mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne).latitude ~= latX && (mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw).longitude...(mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne).longitude ~= lngY) {
    print("VISIBLE")
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a way to do it.

I just calculate the percentage of my mapview hidden by the bottom view and I minus this number to the south latitude :

```
var valueToRemoveBottom = (mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne).latitude - (mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw).latitude
let percentageUsedByBottom = (bottomView.frame.height * 100 / mapView.frame.height) / 100
valueToRemoveBottom = valueToRemoveBottom * Double(percentageUsedByBottom)

if (((mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw).latitude + valueToRemoveBottom)...((mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne).latitude) ~= latX && (mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.sw).longitude...(mapView.visibleCoordinateBounds.ne).longitude ~= lngY) {
// visible
}
```